# Titan Graph DB - using Gremlin Pipeline

Tags: java, performance, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

What is the best way to make paging with sort order in TitanDB (ASC/DSC)?

I want to use GremlinPipeline with Java 8 sort support.

Something like this:

```
new  GremlinPipeline().start(userVertex).outE(EDGE_LABEL_NOTIFIED).order(" HERE I WANT TO MAKE DSC ORDER").range()...
```

Thanks,

Comment: What version of TitanDB are you using?

Comment: Hi, i use "titan-0.5.4-hadoop2" and cassandra "dsc-cassandra-2.1.9" , the major jars for Pipelien: gremlin-java-2.2.0.jar, pipes-2.3.0.jar ,blueprints-core-2.5.0.jar

Comment: Thanks. You should probably keep all of your TinkerPop-related jars (gremlin, pipes, blueprints) aligned with version 2.5.0 because that's the version that Titan 0.5.4 uses.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Titan 0.5.4 documentation where [index ordering](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/indexes.html#_ordering) is described. You will need to use `orderBy('someprop', Order.DESC)` based on a property on the edge. Also pay attention to the notes described in the documentation, in particular:

> - Composite graph indexes do not natively support ordering search results. All results will be retrieved and then sorted in-memory. For
>     large result sets, this can be very expensive.
> - Mixed indexes support ordering natively and efficiently. However, the property key used in the orderBy method must have been previously
>     added to the mixed indexed for native result ordering support. This is
>     important in cases where the orderBy key is different from the query
>     keys. If the property key is not part of the index, then sorting
>     requires loading all results into memory.

Comment: TNX cool , but my main issue is Paging feature on the server side, i made ordering something like ,  Spliterator<Edge> notificationsEdgeSpl = userVertex.query()
                .labels(EDGE_LABEL_NOTIFIED)
                .direction(Direction.OUT)
                .orderBy(EDGE_PROPERTY_TIME, Order.DESC)
                .edges().spliterator();  , but i want use Pipeline because it can make range(int low, int high)